# How to exclude library from AAR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build.gradle, exclude-constraint

[image]
I need to exclude `androidx.core` from `natshare-core-1.3.0:@arr/classes.jar`

`implementation(name: 'NatShare', ext:'aar') { exclude group: 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0' }`
`implementation(name: 'NatShare', ext:'aar') { exclude group: 'androidx.core' }`
`implementation(name: 'NatShare', ext:'aar') { exclude module: 'androidx.core' }`
Nothing of these works